# Reader wont read on Page Load, but does when its method is called regularly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, pageload

On my page I have this button, which calls this method, it works. However, when I set that same method, to be called during Page Load it works, but not completely. The method has a few readers, they read from the database and show the information, there's no issue when the method is ran reguarly, but on Page Load the readers never read.

This is one my select statements that fuel the reader:

```
sql.CommandText = "select temp from forecast where zone='" + myzone + "' and date=TO_DATE('" + mydate + "','dd/mm/yyyy') order by zone,date,time"
        sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        reader = sql.ExecuteReader()
        Dim x As Integer
        While (reader.Read())
            data(0, x) = reader.Item("temp").ToString()
            x += 1
        End While
```

Again, when ran as a button click once the page is loaded it reads, when ran during Page Load it doesn't read.
It cannot be the select statement since the same exact statement works when the button is clicked. Also both variables are working and have the values they should when the statement is executed during Page Load so it can't be that either. Also tried with both Load and Init and none will work.

My Button Click:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.myMethod()
End Sub
```

And the Page Load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.myMethod()
End Sub
```

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be putting `If NOT Me.IsPostBack` around the `Me.myMethod()` in the `Page_Load`?

Comment: I did and still it finds nothing to read during Page Load..

Comment: Do `myzone` and `mydate` have the expected values when you call the method in the Page_Load event?

Comment: Yes @AndrewMorton, just before calling the method on Page_Load I assign the values to the variables, the same values they are assigned regularly.